# PHP time: Add variable number of weeks to start date

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to place the result of the $total variable as the number for the $addedWeeks variable. $total is the sum of numbers I separately added into a form. I can get the sum of numbers, but I don't know how to add that sum to the $newDate variable.

```
$total = 0.0;
while(the_repeater_field( 'timeline_box' )):
    $total += get_sub_field( 'timeline_time' );
endwhile;
$oldDate = '2016-07-30';
$addedWeeks = $total;
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($oldDate. " + {$addedWeeks} weeks"));
echo $newDate;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use an integer as I dont think you can add something like 2.4 weeks

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. When I manually add 2.4 weeks to the $addedWeeks variable, I do get the desired result.

Comment: Strange, when I try to add `2.4` weeks to `2016-07-01` I always get `1970-01-01` which means that `strtotime()` failed! But if I add 2 weeks I get the right answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I looked into this further and you are right about the integer.

Comment: Anyway, how many days is `.4` of 7 days?

Comment: Right. I ended up rounding up to get an integer, then using Abel's suggestion to come up with a workable result. Thanks, @RiggsFolly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly... But, does this achieve what you want?

```
$oldDate = new DateTime('2016-07-30');
$oldDate->modify("+{$addedWeeks} week");
echo $oldDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. If I round up to get a whole integer, then I'm able to get the result I'm looking for using your suggestion. Here's the final code: `$total = 0.0;
      while(the_repeater_field( 'timeline_box' )):
      $total += get_sub_field( 'timeline_time' );
      endwhile;
      $weeks = ceil($total);
      $addedWeeks = $weeks;
      $oldDate = new DateTime('2016-07-30');
      $oldDate->modify("+{$addedWeeks} weeks");
      echo $oldDate->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Then why are you using float numbers? xD

Comment: So I can add partial weeks. Rounding up at the point above works for me. But I need it to show up as a decimal elsewhere.

Comment: Then you should use days instead of weeks... I have never heard people talk about 2.69 or 3.16 weeks